# What does "Embedded" mean?

Tags: hardware, cpu, intel, processor

I notice that Core i3-330M is specified as "Embedded" while the Core i5-430 is not. What technically does "Embedded" mean?

Here is where I see the speicfication:

i3-330M: http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=47663

i5-430M: http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=43537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded with CPUs means devices that are designed to be used within devices that may not appear to be computers. E.g. a television or a washing machine is an embedded system. In practice it tends to mean that the part has very low power (both power usage and computational power) and possibly otherwise limited resources. On the other hand, it may have more I/O capability and more integrated devices that other chips do.

In the case of the CPU you mention AFAIK the only differences are low power and using a different socket than desktop versions do.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of Intel's documentation (e.g. the ARK site), an "Embedded" processor means it is under the care of Intel's Embedded group.  This means the processor will be manufactured for a while (typically 7 years or more).  It also probably has one or more compatible chipsets that are "Embedded" as well.

Intel's processors and chipsets normally have a pretty short manufacturing lifespan (1-2 years).  This is not a good thing if you want to design the chip into a product that will be around for several years (industrial machinery, military hardware, etc).

Comment: also may be offered in industrial temperature range of -40 to +85C, and if you're lucky in  -40 to +125C

Comment: If the part is available in a broader temperature range, Intel's documentation will usually indicate that in the Tjunction field under Package Specifications.  Note that Tjunction is the **internal** temperature of the chip, not the external temperature (Tcase or Tambient).  You might need to dig into the actual datasheet for the chip to find those number (if they are specified at all, sometimes they are not).

Comment: Here is an example of a Industrial Temperature Intel chip.  http://ark.intel.com/products/78477/Intel-Atom-Processor-E3826-1M-Cache-1_46-GHz  Note the Tjunction is -40 to +110C, whereas for the i5 processor that was linked to in the original question it is only speced for +105C (no lower end defined).